# AHK: Copying a block of text into an array, modifying, and transferring to another array

Tags: arrays, loops, parsing, split, autohotkey

Alright so the question is hard to word. I've googled this several times, but usually it turns out I'm not googling the right phrases, and the answer is readily available. I do work as a medical biller for a doctors office, and I have to include diagnosis codes for the office visits. In the Electronic Medical Record program, there's a diagnosis list. The first line is the doctors description, I don't care about that. The second line is an ICD-9 code. Those are old, I don't care about those either. The third line (every third line) contains the ICD-10 code. That's what I need. What I'd like to be able to do is grab the whole list, dump it into an array delimited by new lines, and get rid of every element that doesn't contain a specific string. Then, dump all the kept elements into another array (or the same one, but not separated by 3 like they would be after the removals) and remove that prefixed string that I kept elements based on. After that, I need to click a specific spot (I know how to do this), add exactly four of the arrays elements as text (can't figure this out), hit enter, and keep adding and hitting enter until I've entered all of the array. I will post what I've tried cobble together from google searches if anyone wants to see that mess. But a general explanation on how to do this would also be appreciated. Thanks.

first of all, the stuff I'd be copying would look like this (actual example)

> Lumbar stenosis - Primary
>
> ICD-9-CM: 724.02
>
> ICD-10-CM: M48.06
>
> Spondylolisthesis of lumbar region
>
> ICD-9-CM: 738.4
>
> ICD-10-CM: M43.16
>
> Lumbar degenerative disc disease
>
> ICD-9-CM: 722.52
>
> ICD-10-CM: M51.36
>
> Chronic bilateral low back pain with bilateral sciatica
>
> ICD-9-CM: 724.2, 724.3, 338.29
>
> ICD-10-CM: M54.42, M54.41, G89.29

Naturally the list would be much longer.
The string I'd look for to keep the lines would be "ICD-10-CM: ", just so you guys know. I DID try using it as a delimiter, in quotes, but got some really quite weird results. It would have made this problem slightly easier to solve had that worked as the delimiter.

```
Arrays:={}
RealArray:={}
^j::
sendinput, ^c
sleep 20
bigone:=ClipBoard
sleep 2000
;StringReplace, bigone, newbigone, `n, "DLMTR", All
;Arrays:= StrSplit(newbigone, "DLMTR")
StringSplit, Arrays, bigone, `n
k=4
j=1
loop
{
if (k<Arrays.Max_Index)
{
RealArray%j%=Arrays%k%
j++
k++
k++
k++
}
else
return
}
return

^L::
a=0
loop
{
if (a<RealArray.Max_Index)
{
send RealArray%a%
a++
sendinput, {Space}
if(mod(a,5)==0)
sendinput, {enter}
}
else
return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Program**

*^j collects codes containing "ICD-10", ^k pastes the codes formatted 5 per line*

```
^j::copyit()
^l::pasteit()


copyit()
{
  sendinput, ^c
  sleep 20
  bigone := ClipBoard
  sleep 100

  global matches
  matches := []
  numMatches := 0
  Loop parse, bigone, `n
    Loop parse, A_LoopField, `,
      if InStr(A_LoopField, "ICD-10")
        matches[++numMatches] := trim( substr(A_LoopField, InStr(A_LoopField, ":") + 1), " `t`n`r")
}


pasteit()
{
  global matches
  for index, element in matches
  {
    Send %element%{SPACE}
    if mod(index,5) == 0
      Send {ENTER}
  }
}
```

**Input:**

```
Recurrent major depressive disorder, in partial remission

ICD-9-CM: 296.35

ICD-10-CM: F33.1

ICD-10-CM:    F33.2
ICD-9-CM: 296.35

ICD-10-CM: F33.3
ICD-10-CM:       F33.4
ICD-9-CM: 296.35

ICD-10-CM:      F33.5,   ICD-10-CM: X432.6,   ICD-10-CM: Y232.6
ICD-10-CM: F33.6

ICD-9-CM: 296.35
```

**Output:**

```
F33.1 F33.2 F33.3 F33.4 F33.5 
X432.6 Y232.6 F33.6
```

Comment: That looks absolutely amazing. I'm gonna give that a shot in a few minutes here, wasted too much time this morning on this, gotta catch up a bit. Thank you so much. I also really appreciate you using my variable names. It makes it easier for me to understand. Thanks a ton!


Just gave it a shot, it works great! I'll dissect it later so I can understand it. Could you perhaps show me how to remove the "ICD-10-CM: " part of each string as well? I can't wrap my head around for loops in AHK, so used to c++.

Comment: I'm commenting the code line by line, and I understand most of it (except for the stuff where I can't alter it to make it do what I want) but I'm having trouble understanding    
    if InStr(A_LoopField, "ICD-10")   
ICD-10 is going to appear multiple times, how does this do anything but return 1 (as in true)?

Comment: Ignore the second half of my first comment. I figured out why. I'm an idiot. Needed an additional set of brackets for the if when I add a second statement. Basic stuff xD

Comment: I updated the program and output to remove "ICD-10-CM: " from matching lines

Comment: That, my good sir, is absolutely sexy. Much more elegant than the solution I went with. I just trimmed it by 11 characters right before each element is added to the array. I'm running into a new issue now, I blanked on it before, but sometimes the doctors put two ICD-10s on the same line, separated by a comma. And I can't figure out how to split them up as it's an issue with the character limit in the billing software. Sometimes it's three ICD-10s. I think an ifinstring statement for commas should do what I want, but I don't know how to split the two or three codes into different elements.

Comment: I'm also having an issue with the program going too fast I think, because once the first four are in, it skips the first one of every subsequent set, and I can't figure out where to put the sleeps to make it slow down a bit. In addition to that, I'm having trouble with making the code figure out how many times it needs to open the diagnosis box. Once add is clicked, and the first four are in the dialogue box, it hits enter, but if there's more, it needs to hit enter again. (Plus, if that's not enough, the other program I have is a bully, and jumps itself on top whenever it feels like it

Comment: I updated the program to extract multiple codes separated by commas from each line

Comment: Maybe you can use **WinActivate** liberally to ensure the bully program is not on top

Comment: I actually already use WinActivate liberally lol. The program is simply that much of a bully. I'm fairly certain I fixed the hitting enter issue. I'd post code so you could tell me if I could do it better, but the comment section doesn't like me posting code.. I thought I fixed the comma issue myself, by changing the number we modulus the index  by into a variable and checking each element for a comma and lowering the modulus number by one, but it doesn't work when the fourth element is the one with two in it.

Comment: Unfortunately the program doesn't re-add the ICD-10-CM to each code, it looks like:

    ICD-10-CM: M25.511, G89.29

Comment: Okay, so I grabbed up your updated code, and it only works if ICD-10 is repeated. But I had a thought, if we just look for ICD-10 FIRST and the commas SECOND, and just moved the parsing loop below the if statement (had to add brackets), it seems to do what I want. Though to be honest, I'm still learning new things every day, so I may have broken it and it just works because of some fluke.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the underlying program that you are automating works, I can't tell you when to sleep or send extra ENTERs.

Maybe you can query the state of the screen to determine what to do next (e.g., send codes, extra ENTERs, wait).

I identify the screen state by searching for a small image that uniquely identifies the state the program is in. I make the images using Alt+PrintScrn to capture the entire screen and then use pbrush.exe to crop out small a unique identifying image.

```
; Search screen for image stored in "images/name.png"
; return true if found, false otherwise
find( name )
{
  fname := "images\" . name . ".png"
  ImageSearch x, y, 0,0,A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, *32 %fname%
  return ( ErrorLevel = 0 and x >= 0 and y >= 0 )
}


; Wait for image stored in "images/name.png" to appear on the screen
wait_for( name )
{
  tooltip Waiting for %name%, 100,0,1

  while !find(name)
    sleep 100
}


; business/domain logic bot
automate_screen()
{
  if ( find( "logon" ))
    do_stuff_to_logon()
  else if ( find( "payroll_history" ))
    do_some_other_stuff()
  else if ( find( "payroll_screen1" ))
  {
    sendplay Type this on screen1{enter}01{enter}
    wait_for( "payroll_screen2" )
    sendplay Type this on screen2{enter}
  }
}


main()
{
  loop
  {
    automate_screen()
    sleep 250
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean for you to try to fix that issue lol. I was just complaining. Thanks for the extra help though. The issue with hitting enter is if there's more than five diagnoses, it must re-open the diagnosis box. Once it's clicked the first time (earlier in my code) it becomes the default button (meaning hitting enter will open it). My issue was dynamically figuring out when to hit enter. But I got it with    If (Index == numDx) and Mod(Index, 4) !=0
    SendInput, {Enter}
outside the loop, and
     If (Index < numDx)
      SendInput, {Enter}
inside the loop

Comment: Also, unfortunately, full automation is not an option as there are many things not done the same way every time, so each chart must be manually checked. However, automating adding the dx really saves time.

Comment: just to try a third time here, I asked another question I think you can help me on. I tried tagging you in the question itself, but I think you have to be involved first. I wish there was an easier way to interact directly with specific people. I'd totally bother you with all my questions.